# How many reputation do I need to upload a screenshot?

Tags: support

Like the question says, I am asking how many reputation I need to include a screenshot in my questions or answers. I am currently resorting to external hosting of my images.

Answer (score 3):

I thought it was part of the [New User limits](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/new-user). If that's the case, you'll need 10 rep to pass it.

Comment: It dosen't say explicitly, wierdly enough